# Webdriver I/O - Get Links

Tags: javascript, webdriver

I am attempting to test a web site using Webdriver I/O.

```
var jasmine = require('jasmine');
var webdriverio = require('webdriverio');

var client = null;
var settings = {
    testAbilities: { desiredCapabilities: { browserName: 'phantomjs' } },
};

describe("Test", function() {
  it('Should load Successfully', function(done) {
  client = webdriverio.remote(settings.testAbilities).init()
  .url('http://www.example.com')
  .selectorExecute('//a', function(links) {
    return links;
  }).then(function(links) {
    for (var i=0; i<links.length; i++) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(links[i]));
    }

    done();
  });
});
```

When this test runs, I see the following printed in the `alert` window:

```
{"ELEMENT":"0"}
```

I was expecting a link. How do I get an anchor tag? I would like to get its position so that I can "click" it via my automated test.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can click on an element directly using [click](http://webdriver.io/api/action/click.html) and passing it your selector, no need to retrieve the element or its location first. If your selector matches more than one element, the first one will be clicked.

This example gets all `a` elements, clicks on the first one (there happens to be only one) and waits for a certain title:

```
var options = {
    desiredCapabilities: { 
        browserName: "phantomjs" 
    }
};

describe("Test", function() {

    it("Should load Successfully", function(done) {

        webdriverio
            .remote(options)
            .init()
            .url("http://www.example.com")
            .click("a")
            .waitUntil(function() {
                return this.getTitle().then(function(title) {
                    return title === "IANA — IANA-managed Reserved Domains";
                });
            })
            .end()
            .then(done);

    }, 50000);
});
```

If you actually want to find DOM elements or retrieve their location directly you should use [element](http://webdriver.io/api/protocol/element.html) and [elements](http://webdriver.io/api/protocol/elements.html) (or [getLocation](http://webdriver.io/api/property/getLocation.html) for the latter):

```
webdriverio
    .remote(options)
    .init()
    .url("http://www.example.com")
    .elements("p").then(function(elems){
        console.log(elems.value.length + " paragraph elements found");  
    })
    .getLocation("a").then(function(loc){
        console.log("link location: " + JSON.stringify(loc));   
    })
    .end();
```

`selectorExecute` is rather meant for executing a javascript function passing the results of your selector as arguments.